# PHP pthreads with Laravel DB Connection with ORM queries

Tags: php, laravel, pthreads, appserver

My existing Laravel project is such that all the tasks are executed sequentially. I have identified part of the code which can be run in parallel using PHP threads and can reduce the response time.

So I'm trying to use pthreads, https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/tree/PHP5. The appserver.io is already comes with pthread, thus I'm running project on appserver.io and not apache.

I was able to use pthread successfully. As in creating new PDO connection under `run()` method for each thread and database interaction is working fine using native query like this:

```
self::$connection = new PDO ( 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mydb' , 'myuser' , 'mypass' );
```

But I'm not able to use Laravel's `\DB:connection` the same way. I need to have this working in order to run my code which is written with ORM based queries. How can I create new connection every time under `run()` method?

Comment: Hi, i am also having the same issue, did you go the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not dispatch jobs and just have those jobs run in background (queue them)?

Comment: is this meant as a comment?

Comment: Thanks Ashit for answer. I think adding jobs top queue is good idea. But I guess queue will process them serially. Correct? That is what is happening right now (before multithreading) where every job is getting executed serially. I am hoping using multithreading, each thread can take up that function (which has all mysql queries), execute it (even if more cpu usage, I'm fine as I have good hardware), get results faster.

Answer (score 1):

**Two things you need to consider.**
 1. You should load the vendor file in your threads.
 2. Instead of facade use singleton class in threads.

Hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: @kailash Gajara  i have been experimenting Laravel Artisan command using pthreads to push email. Here is the link [Pthreads+ Laravel](https://github.com/ssatz/PThreadsLaravel) . It might be useful.